# Retrieving the bitmap of a hardware-accelerated Android View

Tags: android, performance, bitmap

Is there any way of retrieving the actual pixel data/bitmap as rendered onto a *hardware-accelerated* View (or possibly Canvas)?

There appears to be plenty of ways of re-rendering the same thing in software and then getting the pixels, but no way of actually getting the bitmap data rendered with hardware-acceleration. For example by using View's drawing cache you seem to get a software-rendered version.

On the other hand, Canvas.setBitmap() only works with non-hardware-accelerated canvases. Canvas.saveLayer() talks about saving to an offscreen bitmap, but I have found no way of retrieving this bitmap.

Comment: have you solved this issue? I'm on the same boat as you now. I want to get screenshot of current screen. I get screenshot of a viewGroup(software_layer) by view.getDrawingCache() or view.draw(). But if there's video in the viewGroup. The video only shows blank. The video may be played in a VideoView or WebView.